# Site Smart Publish job - execute now does not update the "LastRunUTC" variable

Tags: sitecron

In the [sitecron](https://github.com/akshaysura/Sitecron) job - Site smart publish I enabled the job and have the job scheduled to run daily.

But if I try to execute the job manually anytime then I do a `Execute Sitecron job now` which runs the job in the background and I can see it updates in the log file with the actual date time stamp of when it was run.

But why the `LastRunUTC` variable is not getting updated with the current date and time when it was manually executed?

Answer (score 0):

That is expected behavior.

`LastRunUTC` value is updated by the `CustomJobListener` class which is used by SiteCron scheduler.

That's why it's updated only when scheduler executes the job. It's not updated when job is executed manually.